# Angular EventEmitter not emitting?

Tags: angular, eventemitter

I think I'm misunderstanding the concept of the EventEmitter.

I'm trying to call a function on a custom component when a focusout event has occurred.
Here is my custom-form.component.html:

```
    <div class="flex flex-col">
        <app-input-form 
        [label]="'Some content'"
        [inputName]="'myCustomInput'"
        ...
        (focusOutEvent)="test($event)"
        ></app-input-form>
    </div>
```

I added the test function is my custom-form.component.ts like this:

```
  test(e: any){
    console.log('test');
  }
```

Finally, in my input-form.component.ts (relates to app-input-form), I added my HostListener and my Output like this:

```
  @Output()
  focusOutEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();

  @HostListener('focusout', ['$event']) myFocusOutFunction(){
    console.log('myFocusOutFunction is triggered')
    this.focusOutEvent.emit();
  }
```

This function is triggered when I'm losing focus, but then the test function is never called.

Why isn't it working? focusOutEvent is an output, and myFocusOutFunction where there is the focusOutEvent.emit() works fine, so what am I missing?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Maybe you have to call for "focusout" instead of "(focusOutEvent)" when you call the app-input-form? Sort of ```(focusout)="test($event)"```

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention I already tried that, but this isn't working

Comment: My bad, you are right in calling for (focusOutEvent) since it's the name of your output. Have you made sure the test function is accessible? If you call "test" from other parts of the component does it execute? (public test(e:any){ ... })

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use directly the built-in focusout event in your `input-form.component.html`

`input-form.component.html`

```
<input (focusout)="this.focusOutEvent.emit()">
...
```

`input-form.component.ts`

```
@Output()
focusOutEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

`custom-form.component.html`

```
 <div class="flex flex-col">
    <app-input-form 
    [label]="'Some content'"
    [inputName]="'myCustomInput'"
    ...
    (focusOutEvent)="test()"
    ></app-input-form>
</div>
```

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the OP's original issue is due to the naming collision with the built-in event.